# GMap.NET route multi-color

Tags: gmap.net

I'd like to draw route using GMap.Net's route method.
But, when I added any point into route list with new color, color of all route was changed.
So, it seems to be able to use only one color for a route.
Is there any way to use two or more colors in a route?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
route.Stroke= (Pen)route.Stroke.Clone();
route.Stroke.Color = Color.Orange;
```

Comment: thanks, it works also for me! but as stated [here](http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-tutorial-routes/) (in 2013) `Styling the route`, this may lead to a memory leak, did you check your solution?

Answer (score 0):

While adding new route to list create an object of brush and assign it to route.stroke method as follows

Brush = New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(80, Color.Blue))
r.Stroke = New Pen(Brush, 10)